# multiselect.js via gem multi-select-rails - how best to set width

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

I've added multiselect from http://loudev.com/  via the multi-select-rails gem to my site.

It works well and I like it. The bit I'm stuck with is how best to modify the default width. It's currently coded to a width 370px via css, when, in Development I change width to 100% I get what I want, but editing vendor files feels very wrong, especially for production

I've tried setting a custom class up, and .multiSelect( {cssClass: "myclass"}) with a width attribute - no joy.

Do I stop with the gem approach and paste the js and css files into my app manually, or am I missing something? Can I override the css setting without overwriting the vendor code? Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with this gem and fixed it by including my custom.css.scss after the multiselect.css.scss import within my application.css.scss file.

```
@import "multi-select";
@import "custom"
```

I added the following to my custom.css and it worked just fine.

```
.ms-container{
    background: transparent image-url('switch.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    width: 75%;
 }
```

Comment: Wow - this was a while ago, but I came back to the issue today, and you've given me the edge - it's now fixed - you are right - it is the order, however with mine, I also had:  "*= require_tree ". above the  "*= require multi-select", which I think also overrid things. So I changed the order, and hey presto - it's all working. Many many thanks!